# Variation of height of a person when subjected to acceleration

Tags: classical-mechanics, acceleration

Why does the height of a person vary when they are subjected to acceleration in, for example, a rocket sled?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a video, or some series of stills?

Comment: Because your body is not perfectly rigid, but responds to force vaguely like a spring.

Comment: Yes you can find them in second chapter of Fundamentals of physics by Halliday.

Comment: @Jon Custer can you elaborate?

Comment: Your spine is not rigid - it can compress under force. (Of course, your bones compress as well under force, just not as much as soft tissue).

Comment: Can horizontal acceleration affect it?